# Where can I find ready-to-use Elcipse Paho Android Service/Client JAR files?

Tags: android, mqtt

Compiling from source with Android Studio seems to be rocket science and I really just want to USE the clien library and service. Does anyone know where to download the Paho Android Service jar and the Paho Java Client library jar?

http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/

There is a link on that page that ironically links back to itself. Any idea? I'd also consider a different android lib if it is small and reliable.

Comment: You've tried to use maven on command line? It just works for me. `mvn clean install` does the trick.

Comment: Have you found out the link? Please share if you got it. I am searching for the Android service jar

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse maintains two repositories where you can find them:

For **stable** releases:

> https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/

For **nightly** snapshots:

> https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/

With the latest jar being at:

> https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.2/

Comment: But are there service jar files for android?

Comment: @Serob_b See [here](https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.android.service/1.1.1/)